# How to get my Program to read my SMS response using Twilio

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

I can send an SMS message to my phone very easily based on the tutorials that Twilio provides, however, I can't seem to find a way to get my program to read the message that I respond with via my cell phone.  Is this even possible?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Login to the Twilio Account
        string AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        var Twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
        var message = Twilio.SendMessage("+TwilioNumber", "+CellNumber", "Hello World"); 

        var sms = Twilio.GetMessage(message.Sid);
        Console.Write(sms.Body);            
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You absolutely can receive messages sent to your Twilio number and read the incoming messages. I recommend you take a read through this messaging QuickStart for C#: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms

You can then follow that up by checking out the API documentation for how Twilio sends the incoming message to you: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This does help.  I have found that my problem is that I do not know how to properly make HTTP POST/GET Requests and I am having trouble learning what goes into it (How to make the Uri address to grabbing the XML file that holds all the data I want)  Any references to that information would be very beneficial to me and thank you for giving me such a detailed response!

Comment: In order to read incoming messages, you actually need to be able to receive an incoming HTTP POST request. The best way to do this is by using a web framework in .NET (.NET MVC for example). This blog post, by my colleague and .NET expert Marcos, shows you how to set it all up for phone calls, though SMS is pretty similar: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/07/making-and-receiving-phone-calls-with-net-mvc-5.html. Take a look through there and you should be up and running in no time.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I learn by very simplified example.  Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Hope it all goes well for you!

Comment: Hi, @Rinktacular, I have the same problem as you did. I even read the article by philnash, I still can't fully understand it. Can you help me with the SMS thing? I also don't know how to properly make HTTP POST/GET request etc.